# add items to custom listview through spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I am trying to add items to custom listview when a spinner is selected using the following code but this is obviously not working. I don't know how to do it. Please help me below is what my little code

```
Spnchapter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) 
        {                
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Spnchapter.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            generateData();             
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    // Spinner

private ArrayList<Item> generateData()
{
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    int verseNumber = 1;
    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from friends where chapter = 1 ", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(!c.isAfterLast()) 
    {
        do 
        {
            String name = c.getString(3);
            if(c.getString(2).length() == 0)
            {                   
                items.add(new Item("", " " + name + " " + c.getString(5)));
            }
            if(!c.getString(2).equals(""))
            {
                items.add(new Item(" " + Integer.toString(verseNumber++), "    " + name));                  
            }       
        } 
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to spinner onItemSelected function. In the below code replace "yourListView" with your the listview you are using.

```
Spnchapter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) 
    {                
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Spnchapter.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ArrayList<Item> items=generateData(); 
        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),items);
        yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

The above code should solve the problem you are facing. If you face any other issue, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much Ramstein I will try it now and i ill let you know

Answer (score 0):

When an item is selected in spinner you are calling the function "generateData()". 
But inside this function you are not doing anything to add items to custom listview. All you are doing is fetch content from database and storing it in arrayList "items".

If you want to add items to list, Then you have add data to your adapter and call yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). If you post code of your listview Adapter I can guide you better in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.row, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.value);

        // 4. Set the text for textView 
        labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDescription());

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this code shows how to use a simple listview:

```
 private String[] mListStr = {"name1","name2","name3","name4"};  
 ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);  
 mListView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListStr));
```

and the result is a simple listview with a string array.

in your code it seems you need to use listview display the item list.
so you need to write your own listview.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
     public final class ListItemView{                //asume your item has 
                                                     //an image'a string and a button   
                public ImageView image;     
                public TextView title;        
                public Button detail;          
         }
    private List<Item> listItems;                  //your data
    private LayoutInflater listContainer;  
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Map<Item> listItems) {   
                this.context = context;            
                listContainer = LayoutInflater.from(context);   //create view   
                this.listItems = listItems;     
           }  
    public int getCount() {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        return listItems.size();   
    }   

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        return null;   
    }   

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        return 0;   
    }
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

    ListItemView  listItemView = null;   
    if (convertView == null) {   
        listItemView = new ListItemView();    
        //get list_item layout   
        convertView = listContainer.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);   
        //get elements   
        listItemView.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);   
        listItemView.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleItem);     
        listItemView.detail= (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.detailItem);   
        //set listitem to convertView   
        convertView.setTag(listItemView);   
    }else {   
        listItemView = (ListItemView)convertView.getTag();   
    }   

    //set text and image
    listItemView.image.setBackgroundResource((Integer) listItems.get(   
            position).get("image"));   
    listItemView.title.setText((String) listItems.get(position)   
            .get("title"));   

    listItemView.detail.setText("click");   
    //set click listener   
    listItemView.detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            //do something
        }   
    });   

    return convertView;   
}     
}
```